# User Control properties not saving in designer

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I've been working on a VB.NET application for about two years now that functions much as a Windows Explorer shell and file browser replacement. I just started to develop a user control that will act like a button but consists of one picturebox and one label. The code for what happens when the item is clicked is already finished but I'm having a problem with the control's properties;

I added two properties to the control, one for the "ButtonText" that will change the text of the label, and one for the "Image" in the picturebox. I read through Microsoft's documentation on control properties [Creating a Windows Form User Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx#winformusecon_topic3c)) and they helped me add properties to the control.

```
Private bttnTxt As String
Private bttnImg As Image

<Category("Appearance"), Description("The text displayed at the bottom of the button control")>
Public Property ButtonText() As String
    Get
        Return bttnTxt
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        Label3.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property

<Category("Appearance"), Description("The image used in the button control")>
Public Property Image() As Image
    Get
        Return bttnImg
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Image)
        PictureBox3.BackgroundImage = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

I built by solution, added the newly added control to my designer of my application's main form and set the values of the "Image" and "ButtonText" properties. However when I add a value to my custom properties, they immediately revert back to nothing.

I need help determining why the values I set in the designer wont stay in the properties.

[image: I've attached an image here to demonstrate my problem.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't saving anything to your variable:

```
Public Property ButtonText() As String
  Get
    Return bttnTxt
  End Get
  Set(ByVal Value As String)
      bttnTxt = Value
      Label3.Text = Value
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Wow... how'd I overlook something like that? Thanks! Really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I needed to override the clone function. See below code example.

Hopefully this helps save some time for someone.

```
Public Class CustomClass_DatGridViewColumn 
    Inherits DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    Private propertyValue As String = ""

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim col As CustomClass_DatGridViewColumn = CType(MyBase.Clone(), CustomClass_DatGridViewColumn)
        col.myProperty = propertyValue
        Return col
    End Function

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), Category("Data"), .Description("description")>
    Public Property myProperty As String
        Get
            Return propertyValue 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            propertyValue = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```